# Probability of rolling 2 dice 10,000 times and getting snake eyes between 280-300 times using probability theory.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

You roll 2 dice 10,000 times.  You are interested in the probability of getting snake eyes(two ones) between 280 and 300 times.  Do two things:  using software, find the exact probability.Second, approximate the probability using methods we have seen in class.  Compare the two results.

I think I might be using the wrong method to find out what the answer is, I used sterlings approximation with gaussian distribution to find the answer and got .00015 as my answer but I think that is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the Binomial Distribution for the exact value?  After that, a normal approximation should be enough.

Comment: What formula for normal approximation?

Comment: First use the Binomial Distribution to get the exact answer.  As you surmise, $.00015$ is far too low.  After all, the mean is $\frac {10^4}{36}\approx 277.78$.

Comment: Using software to simulate this process, you can find an *approximate* probability, which is likely to vary with successive modelling runs, especially if the value is at an extreme (close to $0$ or $1$). Analytical methods will give a precise probability (based on the conditions, like fair dice etc.), even if you then use some approximations to get a useful numerical value.

Comment: Simulation is possible but with software direct binomial probability is easier to find. It seems a normal approximation is also reqired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the question to mean between 280 and 300 *inclusive.*

In R: Exact binomial computation,

$$P(280 \le X \le 300) = 0.3698562.$$

```
diff(pbinom(c(279,300), 10000, 1/36))
[1] 0.3698562
```

Normal approximation,

$$X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} 
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 277.7778, \sigma=16.66667).$$

```
mu = 10000*1/36;  mu
[1] 277.7778
vr = mu*36/36;  vr
[1] 277.7778
sd = sqrt(vr);  sd
[1] 16.66667
```

Using continuity correction:
$$P(279.5 < X< 300.5) = 0.3724605.$$

[You can get close
to this answer by standardizing and using printed
standard normal CDF tables.]

```
mu = 10000*1/36;  mu
[1] 277.7778
vr = mu*36/36;  vr
[1] 277.7778
sd = sqrt(vr);  sd
[1] 16.66667
diff(pnorm(c(279.5,300.5), mu, sd))
[1] 0.3724605
```

Figure:

```
x = 275:315;  pdf = dbinom(x, 10000, 1/36)
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(10000, 1/36) with Approx. Normal Density"
plot(x, pdf, type="h", ylim=c(0,.025), xaxs="i", lwd = 2, main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sd), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=c(279.5, 300.5), col="blue", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]